# Opencart check if specific product is in stock

Tags: php, opencart

I want to be able to check to see if a specific product is in stock or enabled or disabled.  I would then like to put this block of code on the checkout page.  More specifically it will go in Gift_Wrap.xml.  I have a product called Gift Box and it goes out of stock quite frequently.  How can I have it check if that specific product is enabled and then display x y or z.

```
<?php if ($product_id['GIFTBOX']) { ?>              
  if($this->data['status']=$this->language->get('enable'){
    //do this
  }
  else if{
    //do this
  }
<?php } ?>
```

Not sure if I am on the right track or not.  What do I need to call before this to get the data options of that product.  New to Opencart and PHP thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

go to controller/product/product.php

run this, to check product in stock:

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product) { 
if($product['stock'] > 0 && $product['product_id']==$product_id['GIFTBOX'])   { 
}
?>
```

Comment: I feel like this is close to what I need, the only thing I need is to be able to do this outside of controller/product/product.php.  Since I want this block of code on the cart page so that it can display a message I need to run this check outside of product.php.  So how do I hook to it?

Comment: I think it would be something like.  $this->load->model('controller/product/product.php');